# creating a new column in excel based upon an existing column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a column in excel with the following values

```
HostName
-----
sa77.com
ca77cded.com
sa65yacd.com
ca65zededs.com
sa88y.com
sa99ujk8.com
```

Now based upon that I want to create a new column `TagName` such that if first column has `77` then `TagName` should be `ABC` and if first column has `65` then `TagName` should be `DCE` if first column has `88` then `TagName` should be `ZBA` if first column has `99` then `TagName` should be `XYZ`

The hostname can have a different size for every entry. I need to compare 3rd and 4th values of the hostname string

```
TagName
-----
ABC
ABC
DCE
DCE
ZBA
XYZ
```

Comment: it is 3rd and 4th. also edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX({"ABC","DCE","ZBA","XYZ"},MATCH(MID(A2,3,2),{"77","65","88","99"},0))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response, actually i also want to check for `55` instead of just checking for `77`. how the formula is going to look for that one

Comment: Just those three?  You should inform the readers that you have other options.

Comment: @meallhour this formula with its table is easier to upkeep if anything changes than hard coding the values in a nested if.

Comment: not allowed to change the excel sheet. nested if seems correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple formula:

```
=IF(MID(A2,3,2)="77","ABC",IF(MID(A2,3,2)="65","DCE",IF(MID(A2,3,2)="88","ZBA",IF(MID(A2,3,2)="99","XYZ","Error"))))
```

Comment: Hi, the hostname can have a different size for every entry. I have edited my question. can you please provide the updated formula. thanks

Comment: I need to compare 4th and 5th values of the hostname string

Comment: @meallhour then change all the `RIGHT()` to the appropriate `MID()` function.

Comment: i have tried to change it to `=IF(MID(A1,2,2)="77","ABC","Error")` but not working

Comment: I went ahead and changed it to MID but I like Scott's solution better!

Answer (score 0):

Late in the day, another option is to use LOOKUP construct like below.

`=LOOKUP(2,SEARCH(MID(A2,3,2),{65,77,88,99},1),{"DCE","ABC","ZBA","XYZ"})`